# Constructing Lie group from Lie algebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have a 3-dimensional real Lie algebra given by the relations: \begin{equation} [e_1,e_2] = e_2-2e_3\end{equation} \begin{equation} [e_1,e_3] = 2e_2+e_3\end{equation} \begin{equation} [e_2,e_3] = 0\end{equation} I need to describe some Lie group with such Lie algebra as a subgroup in $GL(3,\mathbb{R})$ In the first point of the task, it was necessary to find all the ideals and I did it, but I don't know how this can help in solving the second point.

Comment: It may be easiest to solve your problem using [the Bianchi classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bianchi_classification) in dimension $3$. It looks like your case is Type VII.

Comment: I think I can't use this classification and I have to find another solution.

Comment: You can have a look at some posts here, e.g. [How to obtain a Lie group from a Lie algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54746/how-to-obtain-a-lie-group-from-a-lie-algebra). You Lie algebra is a matrix Lie algebra, and you can easily find matrix Lie groups with this Lie algebra.

Comment: So, I was able to find the group I needed. It can be written as a semidirect product of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $G_1$, where $G_1$ is generated by the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} e^t & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & cos(2t) & sin(2t) \\ 0 & -sin(2t) & cos(2t) \end{pmatrix}$. Now I want to describe all connected Lie groups with such a Lie algebra. To do this, I use the third Lie theorem, that is, I need to find a universal cover of my semidirect product and factorize over all discrete subgroups of the center.  I will assume that this cover will be isomorphic $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, but I'm not sure. Am I right?

Comment: No, that's not correct. The  simply connected covering of a non-Abelian group is non-Abelian.