# Find the centers of $SU_{n}$, $SO_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ and $SL_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ and find all the connected lie groups certian the tangent algebras.

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

I am taking a course in Lie algebra and due to the fact that I am struggling with the concepts I decided to try to solve most of the exercises of a problem sheet, here I came across with this problem and thought it was easy at first but now I'm stuck:

> a) Find the centers of $SU_{n}$, $SO_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ and $SL_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ 
> b) Find all connected Lie groups with the tangent Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$, $\mathfrak{sl}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$, where $n$ is prime.

I solved the first part without any problems, but in the second half of the problem, I had no idea how to continue.
So, for the center of $SU_{n}$ i got $n\mathbb{Z}$.
For the center of $SO_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ I got $\{\pm I\}$ when $n\geq3$ and itself when $n=2$.
And for the center of $SL_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ I got $\{\lambda I:\lambda^{n}=1\}$.
Now, how should I proceed with the second part of the problem? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Over which field are the Lie groups and Lie algebras in part b)? Have you seen some posts here, e.g., [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54746/how-to-obtain-a-lie-group-from-a-lie-algebra)? Start with $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$.

Comment: I would say they are over any field, as the problem doesn't state any. Thank you very much, I'll see if that answer helps. Besides I was talking with a friend in the class and she told me that if I find a discrete subgroup that could help me find all the connected groups.

Comment: All fields? So don't forget to consider the field of $p$-adic numbers $\Bbb Q_p$, and $p$-adic Lie groups, see [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Lie_group,_p-adic), for example.

Comment: Following your first question, I asked today my profesor for clarification and he told me he forgot to include the field, which is ℂ, Ill edit the post, and I think I got the answer, so I will try to respond myself haha

Comment: When you say that the center is $\mathbb{Z}$, which subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ do you mean? The center of $\operatorname{SU}(n)$ is actually much larger than $\mathbb{Z}$ anyway. It is a torus, the product of $n-1$ circles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood the answer was really simple, but I may be wrong.
We know that the center of a group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^{n}$ and $\mathbb{Z}^{n}$ is a discrete space, so we can characterize all connected Lie groups with the following quotients:
$$\mathfrak{su}_{n}(\mathbb{C})/z_{1},$$
and
$$\mathfrak{sl}_{n}(\mathbb{C})/z_{2},$$
where
$z_{1}$ is the center of $SU_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ and $z_{2}$ is the center of $SL_{n}(\mathbb{C})$