# Is every complex Lie algebra a complexification?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm wondering if every finite-dimensional complex Lie algebra can be written as a complexification of a real Lie algebra. At the vector space level, clearly every $\mathbb{C}^n$ is a complexification of $\mathbb{R}^n$, but at the level of bracket structure, it's not clear to me if we can consistently "decomplexify" the Lie algebra. Putting it another way, for any given $n$-dimensional complex Lie algebra, can we find a basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ such that the structure constants are all real?

Comment: I think this is equivalent to having a real form. This claims not every complex Lie algebra has a real form http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Complexification_of_a_Lie_algebra

Comment: @Timkinsella, I did come across that, but the definition of a real form seems more stringent, that every element of the Lie algebra must be uniquely representable in terms of the real form. So if one can prove every complexfication has a real form, then I guess the answer to my question is no.

Comment: @Timkinsella, you are right, after a closer look it is  equivalent to having a real form, I misunderstood the definition of a real form. So indeed the answer is no, however I'd be happy to see a concrete example.

Comment: Try a Google search for "complex real algebra with no real form"

Comment: @Timkinsella, alright thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is no.

A "minimal" example of a complex Lie algebra without a real form is given in example 1.36 of [these lecture notes of Karl-Hermann Neeb's](https://faubox.rrze.uni-erlangen.de/dl/fiMYUbDntWM7oPPUUy3T55Fu/?inline). To spell it out, it is the three-dimensional Lie algebra over $\mathbb C$ with basis $x,y,z$ and commutators

$$[x,y]=0, [z,x]=2x, [z,y] = i y.$$

It is minimal in the sense that every $0$- , $1$-, or $2$-dimensional (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/976271/96384, [Classsifying 1- and 2- dimensional Algebras, up to Isomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/24601/96384)) complex Lie algebra does have a real form.

Note that the above Lie algebra is solvable. On the other end of the spectrum, it is a well-known (although maybe not suffciently celebrated) result of the structure theory that all *semisimple* complex Lie algebras do have real forms -- actually, they can be defined over $\mathbb Q$ or even $\mathbb Z$, a result usually attributed to Chevalley (see "Chevalley basis").

Finally, note that the above example does have a form over the number field $\mathbb Q(i)$. The answers to [Are there finite-dimensional Lie algebras which are not defined over the integers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/95540/96384) (especially user YCor's comment to Qiaochu Yuan's answer) exhibit examples of complex Lie algebras which do not have forms over any number field, nor $\mathbb R$.

Comment: "It is a well-known result of the structure theory that all semisimple complex Lie algebras do have real forms". Could you expand a bit more on that? Is this just a consequence of the classification theorem for semisimple Lie algebra?

Comment: @toyr99: As said, it is a consequence of the existence of a [Chevalley basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley_basis) or more precisely, that all numbers / coefficients that occur in such a Chevalley basis for a simple complex Lie algbera are actually $\in \mathbb Q$. Because now, for any field $\mathbb Q \subset k \subset \mathbb C$, you can just look at the vector space spanned by that basis over that field, and by the relations it is a Lie algebra which, when yo complexify it, gives out the simple complex one you started with. Cf. also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3618376/96384