# What is the meaning of tensor product with a subscript?

Tags: notation, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

In a book about compact Lie groups, I came across this notation
[image]

and don´t know what is the meaning of the subscript $\mathbb{R}$ in the tensor product. Is it tensor product of vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$, even if $\mathfrak{g}$ "lives" in $\mathbb{C}$?

Thank you.

Remark:
$\mathfrak{g}$ = Lie algebra of some Lie subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: For example $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb R)\otimes_{\Bbb R} \Bbb C\cong \mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3975561/96384

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "$\mathfrak{g}$ lives in $\mathbf{C}$". Indeed, every connected complex compact Lie group is abelian, so most likely your Lie algebra is not isomorphic to any complex Lie algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the subscript indicates that the tensor product is of $\mathbb R$-vector spaces (over $\mathbb C$ we have $\mathfrak g  \otimes_{\mathbb C} \mathbb C \simeq \mathfrak g$.).

This makes sense because a $\mathbb C$-vector space $V$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space via $t \cdot v := (t+0i)v$. In other words, we consider the restriction of scalars given by the inclusion $\mathbb R \subset \mathbb C$.

Comment: Why is the  $\mathfrak g  \otimes_{\mathbb C} \mathbb C$ called "compexification" though, when it indicates tensor product of real vector spaces?

Comment: Notice that $\mathbb C$ is an $\mathbb R$-vector space. Thus, if $V$ is a **real** vector space, it makes sense to compute $\mathbb C \otimes_{\mathbb R} V$. This is now a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, scalar multiplication is defined (by linear extension) on elementary tensors as $z \cdot a \otimes b := za \otimes b$. 

Thus we have a "canonical" procedure that, given a real vector space $V$, outputs a complex vector space associated to it. Notice that the tensor is over $\mathbb R$, not over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: (cont.) This is an instance of the general situation called "extension of scalars" whereas the situation of the original question is called "restriction of scalars". These two notions are interwined, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_rings). In these cases the ring map we are considering is the inclusion $\mathbb R \subset \mathbb C$.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the tensor product is considered over the ground field of real numbers. Thus, a tensor product of $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces. This means that we must for example consider $\mathbb{C}$ as a (two-dimensional) space over $\mathbb{R}$.