# Question on complexification of $\mathfrak sl(2,\Bbb C)$

Tags: lie-algebras, quantum-field-theory

As six generators of the **real** Lie algebra $\mathfrak sl(2,\Bbb C)_\Bbb R$ I can use the Pauli matrixes as follow:

$X_1=\frac{1}{2} \sigma_1, X_2=\frac{1}{2} \sigma_2, X_3=\frac{1}{2} \sigma_3$

$Y_1=\frac{1}{2}i \sigma_1, Y_2=\frac{1}{2}i \sigma_2, Y_3=\frac{1}{2}i \sigma_3$

cause it's easy to see that they have null traces and they are linearly independent on $\Bbb R$ span.

Based on Hall "Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations" page 66, a real Lie algebra $\mathfrak g $ of complex $n \times n $ matrix can be complexified only if $iX \notin \mathfrak g $ for every $X \in \mathfrak g$.

The generators above obviously doesn't satisfy that conditions, cause $iX_i = Y_i \in \mathfrak sl(2,\Bbb C)_\Bbb R$.

So it seems I can't complexify $\mathfrak sl(2,\Bbb C)_\Bbb R$ using the generators above.
However, on some books of QFT the complexification of $\mathfrak sl(2,\Bbb C)_\Bbb R$ is mentioned using as generators the standard generators of the rotations and boosts, and it's mentioned also in the following Wiki:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group

So my questions are:

1. Does the complexification exist or doesn't exist depending on the generators used?
2. Is $\mathfrak sl(2,\Bbb C)_\Bbb C \cong sl(2,\Bbb C)_\Bbb R \oplus sl(2,\Bbb C)_\Bbb R$ ?

Comment: Please quote exactly what Hall writes there. If by complexification of a real Lie algebra $L$ we mean $\mathbb C \otimes_{\mathbb R} L$ (and I don't think I have ever seen it mean anything else), then of course one can complexify every real Lie algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As regards question 2, you seem to be using subscripts for two different things. If subscript $\mathbb C$ stands for complexification but subscript $\mathbb R$ stands for scalar restriction to $\mathbb R$, then a) please use a different notation and b) it is still not true. Cf. answers to [Are Lie algebra complexifications $\mathfrak g_{\mathbb C}$ equivalent to Lie algebra structures on $\mathfrak g\oplus \mathfrak g$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3884795/96384) and [Is the complexification of $\mathfrak{sl}(n, \mathbb{C})$ itself?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3974731/96384).

What is true is

$$sl(2, \mathbb C) \otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C\simeq sl(2, \mathbb C) \oplus sl(2, \mathbb C)$$

where both sides are *complex* Lie algebras and the isomorphism is one of complex LAs. If you view both sides as real Lie algebras via scalar restriction (and we denote that by the subscript $\mathbb R$), then this implies, of course, that there is an isomorphism of *real* Lie algebras

$$(sl(2, \mathbb C) \otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C)_\mathbb R \simeq sl(2, \mathbb C)_{\mathbb R} \oplus sl(2, \mathbb C)_{\mathbb R}.$$

[So the left hand side is the complexification but viewed as a real algebra again, i.e. complexification followed by scalar restriction; if you insist on sticking to your confusing notation -- which you shouldn't -- you should write the left hand side as $(sl(2, \mathbb C)_{\mathbb C})_{\mathbb R}$.]

Comment: I am using the same $_\Bbb C$ notation as the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group, in "The Lie Algebra" section, my understanding is that it means complexification, but I may be wrong and it means the $\Bbb C$ scalar, not the complexification

Comment: However, Hall book seems to use $_\Bbb C$ to mean complexification, cause it says as an example " The complex Lie algebra $ \mathfrak g_\Bbb C$ is called the complexification of the real Lie algebra  $ \mathfrak g$." (pag 65), now I'm really confused

Comment: Yes, both sources use the subscript for complexification (and that is quite standard, and so do I myself in the answers to the linked questions). But in your question you use the subscript $\mathbb R$ for scalar restriction. I am sure one can find some other source that also does it. But is it not clear that it's a bad idea to use it for both?

Comment: Yes, you are tight, I was confused cause I thought complexification of real LA was equivalent to the complex LA (that Is the LA on $\Bbb C$ field instead of  $\Bbb R$), but after reading your answer I get I was wrong

Comment: Actually I'am also confused by the use of $\oplus$ symbol, as far as I know direct sum of vector space is defined when $V_1 \cap V_2 = \emptyset$, since LAs are vector spaces I don't understand the meaning of $sl(2,\Bbb C) \oplus sl(2,\Bbb C)$. What am I missing or thinking wrong?

Comment: There is an abstract notion of direct sum of vector spaces. You can write $\mathbb R^2 \simeq \mathbb R \oplus \mathbb R$, can you not? To be super precise, one can write $\simeq \mathbb R\pmatrix{1\\0} \oplus \mathbb R \pmatrix{0\\1}$ or something. Those are "two distinct copies" of $\mathbb R$, and in your situation it are two distinct copies of $sl(2, \mathbb C)$. They are structurally identical (like clones), but not the same, they indeed would have empty intersection.

Comment: Actually by reading the following wiki
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification
it seems that it can been written more precise as $sl(2,\Bbb C) \oplus isl(2,\Bbb C)$

Comment: Yes and no. One has an iso $L_{\mathbb C} \simeq L \oplus iL$ of *real vector spaces* for any real Lie algebra $L$. However, notice that the second summand is not closed under the Lie bracket, and neither is a complex vector space. What is remarkable in the case $L = sl(2, \mathbb C)$ viewed as a real Lie algebra is that there is also an isomorphism *of complex Lie algebras*  $sl(2, \mathbb C) \simeq sl(2, \mathbb C) \oplus sl(2, \mathbb C)$ i.e. there exist ...

Comment: ... there exist  two distinct complex subalgebras, with intersection $0$, each of them $\simeq sl(2, \mathbb C)$, in the LHS. Those are *not* the real subspaces $1 \otimes sl(2, \mathbb C)$ and $i \otimes sl(2, \mathbb C)$ in the other decomposition. Rather, those complex $sl(2, \mathbb C)$-factors lie rather "skew" inside the tensor product. It's agood exercise to find them explicitly. --- Note that the comments and my answer to the first linked post discuss very similar issues.