# First realisation, then complexification of a simple complex Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

I saw the following exercise on Knapp's famous textbook 'Representation Theory of Semisimple Groups. It's exercise 3 of chapter 1.

Suppose $\mathfrak{ g}$ is a complex simple Lie algebra ( of finite dimension). First regard it as a real Lie algebra, then consider its complexification. The exercise is: prove that after these operations, the obtained complex Lie algebra is not simple.

I tried to write down a set of basis and consider their explicit changes to find a nontrivial ideal. ( Because I had no idea which theorem I could use directly.) But I didn't succeed.

Any hint or suggestion would be welcome. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4158558/on-a-simple-real-lie-algebra-whose-complexification-is-not-simple). Try it with $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)$ first.

Comment: Also compare answers to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3974731/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4177437/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3884795/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4271257/96384.