# Lie Algebras with lower dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

$\forall\ L$ is a Lie algebra, if $\rm{dim}_{\mathbb{R}}L=2$, can we have $L$ is solvable? Is there any example of $L$ which fits these condition but $L$ is not nilpotent?

Comment: Two dimension is easy to calculate by hand. Can you even write up a nontrivial Lie bracket on a 2d real vector space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are exactly two different Lie algebras over a field $K$, namely the abelian Lie algebra $K^2$ and the non-abelian Lie algebra $\mathfrak{r}_2(K)$, with basis $(x,y)$ and Lie bracket $[x,y]=x$. Both Lie algebras are solvable. The non-abelian Lie algebra has trivial center, hence cannot be nilpotent.

References:

[Two Dimensional Lie Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222743/two-dimensional-lie-algebra)

[Two dimensional Lie Algebra - what do we know without knowing the Bracket?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1384110/two-dimensional-lie-algebra-what-do-we-know-without-knowing-the-bracket)