# 2-dimensional derived subalgebra of 3-dimensional Lie algebra is abelian

Tags: lie-algebras

I saw a question which was about a 3-dimensional Lie algebra with a 2-dimensional derived subalgebra, and it was asserted that the derived subalgebra must be abelian. If $\mathfrak{g}$ is 3-dimensional with 2-dimensional derived subalgebra $[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]$, is the derived subalgebra nessecarily abelian.

Could someone show me a proof of this as I've been unable to prove it myself. Thanks very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two Dimensional Lie Algebra](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222743/two-dimensional-lie-algebra)

Comment: @Wauzl, it is not a duplicate. This question is about $2$-dimensional algebras which are the derived algebra of a $3$-dimensional algebra.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, I'm not asking for a classification of 2-dimensional Lie algebras, I'm asking if $\mathfrak{g}$ is 3-dimensional with 2-dimensional derived subalgebra $[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]$, is the derived subalgebra nessecarily abelian

Comment: Sorry. I should go to bed. But at least it made you write the subalgebra explicitly in your question ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A $2$-dimensional subalgebra is solvable, and abelian if nilpotent.

It follows from that that if $g$ is a $3$-dimensional Lie algebra with $\dim g'=2$, then $g$ is solvable. Indeed, there is then a short exact sequence $0\to g'\to g\to g/g'\to0$ and both the ideal $g'$ and the quotient $g/g'$ are solvable.

Now a solvable Lie algebra has nilpotent derived algebra, so $g'$ is $2$-dimensional and nilpotent. Our opening observation, then, implies that $g'$ must be abelian.

Comment: So this claim relies on Lies theorem for the part `solvable Lie algebra has nilpotent derived algebra'? And might be false over finite fields?

Comment: Well, you can simply classify all 3-dimensional Lie algebras —it is not hard at all— and then do a case by case analysis.