# The notation for a non-abelian two dimensional Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

Most of the introductions into Lie algebras start with the notion of a two-dimensional non-abelian Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g} = \langle x,y\rangle$ such that $[x,y]=x$. Is there a common notation for this one?

Comment: It is the Lie algebra of the affine group in 1-dimension. I've seen it written as $\mathfrak{aff}(1)$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_low-dimensional_real_Lie_algebras) for example

Comment: In the French literature (and also in others)  it is $\mathfrak{r}_2(K)$, where the "r" stands for "resoluble", which means solvable. And $K$ is an arbitrary field. See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3208548/classifying-all-2-dimensional-lie-algebras-up-to-isomorphism).

Comment: @Callum Thanks!

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you!