# Is the fundamental group of non orientable surface Fuchsian?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces, geometric-topology, non-orientable-surfaces

Let M be the connected sum of 3 projective planes. Then is the fundamental group of M a Fuchsian group?

This group is an extension of the two element group by the surface group for a genus 2 surface (which is a Fuchsian group). So it seems very close to Fuchsian.

Recall that the connected component of the isometries of the sphere, plane and hyperbolic plane are $ SO_3, SE_2, PSL_2=SO_{2,1} $ respectively.

The nonorientable surface $ N_0 $ (which is just the projective plane) is given by
$$
N_0 \cong SO_3/O_2
$$
where $ SO_2 $ is the connected group of rotations around z axis
$$
SO_2= \left \{ \
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & 0 \\
-b & a & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} : a^2+b^2=1 \right \} 
$$
and
$$
r:=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so that $ <r,SO_2> \cong O_2 $. The orientable double cover is the sphere $ \Sigma_0 $
$$
\Sigma_0 \cong S^2 \cong SO_3/SO_2
$$
Similarly for the the non orientable surface $ N_1 $ (the connected sum of two projective planes, in other words the Klein bottle) we have
$$
SE_2= \left \{ \
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & x \\
-b & a & y \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} : a^2+b^2=1 \right \} 
$$
there is a connected group $ V $ of translations up each vertical line
$$
V= \left \{ \ 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & y \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} : y \in \mathbb{R} \right \} 
$$
There is also an element that shifts horizontally by one unit
$$
b:=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now if we include the rotation by 180 degrees
$$
\tau:=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
then
$$
N_1 \cong SE_2/<V,b, \tau>
$$
And the orientable double cover is the torus $ \Sigma_1 $
$$
\Sigma_1 \cong T^2 \cong SE_2/<V,b>
$$
Is something similar true for $ N_2 $ the connected sum of 3 projective planes? The orientable double cover here is a genus 2 surface $ \Sigma_2 $. Then
$$
\Sigma_2 \cong \Gamma \backslash SL_2 /SO_2
$$
where $ \Gamma $ is a Fuchsian surface group. Is there another Fuchsian group $ \Gamma' $ containing $ \Gamma $ as a index two subgroup such that
$$
N_2 \cong \Gamma' \backslash SL_2 /SO_2
$$

Comment: What is your definition of a Fuchsian group?

Comment: Discrete subgroup of PSL_2(R)

Comment: You should edit your question to make this definition clear. A hint for the solution: Fundamental group determines the topology of a compact connected surface without boundary.

Comment: The answer was is no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are misinterpreting what is said in the link.

The proof is by contradiction. Suppose that $\pi=\pi_1(M)$ is isomorphic to a Fuchsian subgroup $\Gamma< G= PSL(2,R)$. The group  $G$ acts (and properly) conformally on the upper half-plane $U$. Thus, $\Gamma$ acts properly discontinuously and conformally on $U$ as well. Hence, the quotient $S=U/\Gamma$ is a Riemann surface (a 1-dimensional complex manifold) satisfying $\pi_1(S)\cong \Gamma\cong \pi = \pi_1(M)$. Hence, due to asphericity of $M$ and contractibility of $U$, the surfaces $S$ and $M$ are homotopy-equivalent. Since $M$ is compact, you get $H_2(M, Z_2)=Z_2$. Hence, $H_2(S, Z_2)=Z_2$. From this, you conclude that $S$ is also compact. But $S$ is orientable, hence, $H_2(S)\cong Z$, while $H_2(M)=0$.

Comment: It seems like your argument just rests on the fact that $ PSL_2 $ acts conformally so the quotient still carries a complex structure and thus is orientable. Why doesn't this same argument apply to the two examples I gave above? Does $ SE_2 $ not acts conformally on the torus? Does $ SO_3 $ not acts conformally on the sphere? So how is it possible that I got the (non orientable) Klein bottle and projective plane as double coset spaces of these two groups?

Comment: I did not read your examples. Yes, all I am using is conformality and that conformality implies orientability. I just read your first example, it is wrong, since the action of $r$ is not free, the quotient is $S^2$, not $P^2$. I assume, the other example is wrong too.

Comment: Oh dear I'm terribly sorry looks like I misplaced a single minus sign in the matrix $ r $. Fixed now. I think the other example is correct as well since I got it directly from your answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3233411/is-every-compact-solvmanifold-the-quotient-of-a-simply-connected-solvable-lie-gr

Comment: The example is as wrong as it was before. Your involution still does not act freely. In fact, a self-map of the 2-sphere homotopic to the identity necessarily has at least one fixed point, it's just a general topological fact. In the linear algebra setting (which is what you are righting) it is quite easy to see.

Comment: Oh I see. I was acting as if whenever $ G $ is a group with connected subgroup $ H $ and discrete subgroup $ \Gamma $ then the coset space $ G/<H,\Gamma> $ is the same as the double coset space $ \Gamma \backslash G / H $. But in fact this is rarely true. In particular, for both my examples $ \Gamma $ does not have a fixed point free action on $ G/H $ ( $ r $ has two fixed points on the sphere $ SO_3/SO_2 $ and $ \tau $ has two fixed points on the cylinder $ SE_2/V $) so the action is not free. Thanks for the helpful feedback! I have edited my answer to remove the incorrect assertions.